# TALEND tMap - how to use wildcard in string match?

Tags: java, wildcard, talend

I have a TALEND ETL job which I'm trying to modify slightly.

In one of the `tMap` I have an expression like this:

```
row.regulation.equals("Reg200806.s3.2a") || row.regulation.equals("Reg200806.s3.2b")
```

Is there a way to make this match any string ending in `'.2a'` or `'.2b'`. I'm guessing that I can wildcard like how % works in SQL. Does anyone know what is the correct wildcard to use in TALEND? (I believe that is is all java under the hood)

Thanks
JP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use java expression in Talend to achieve this. use below expression and test whether it works or not.

```
row.regulation.endsWith(".2a") || row.regulation.endsWith(".2b")
```